# How to efficiently count all paths between two nodes in Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

In a neo4j database, I have created 4 node types: A, B, C and D each one with 1500 nodes.

For each node a in A and d in D, I want to find the tuples (a, d, count) where count is the number of paths of type A->B->C->D that connect nodes a and d.

I have tried the following Cypher query:

```
CALL apoc.export.csv.query("MATCH (a:A)-[:AB]->(b:B)-[:BC]->(c:C)-[:CD]->(d:D) RETURN a.`_id`, d.`_id`, count(*)", "results.csv", {})
```

that seems to return correct results but needs ~40 seconds to execute.
Adding one more relation to the path seems to dramatically increase the execution time.

Is there a way to optimize such a query?

The query plan is the following [image: here]

I have increased the ulimit in the server and set

```
dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=5100m
dbms.memory.heap.max_size=5100m
dbms.memory.pagecache.size=6900m
```

in neo4j configuration as `neo4j-admin memrec` suggests.

Comment: How long does it take if you do not export to a file? Also, what neo4j version are you using? I don't see the same profile with 3.5.8.

Comment: Also, what is the total number of paths found?

Comment: I also 3.5.8 community edition. Without exporting to a file, the query runs in 32 seconds. The query returns 1,927,493 tuples in the form (source_node, target_node, count_of_paths). Each tuple counts only a few paths (for most of them less than 10)

Note that when adding two more relations to the same query, the execution time is increased to approximately two hours.

Comment: How many relationships of each type are there in the graph? You can use `CALL apoc.meta.stats()` to get this info, if you have APOC installed.

Comment: Assuming _id properties are unique per node of the given label, one thing you can do to improve is aggregate based on the node, not the unique id, and only do property access after the aggregation is complete. So instead of your RETURN, do: `WITH a, d, count(*) as count RETURN a.`_id`, d.`_id`, count", "results.csv", {})`

Comment: **Relationship types:** :AB (22382), :BC (22388), :CD (22387)

@InverseFalcon Nice idea, but this modification seems to slow down the query, it runs in 37 seconds instead of 32.

In fact, he query plan looks exactly the same but a projection step is also added after "Eager Aggregation"

Comment: Is that after repeated runs? You'll want to make sure you see how it performs when that portion of the graph is in the pagecache. Speaking of which you may want to tune your memory configuration so the pagecache is able to encompass the graph if possible (check for cache misses in the PROFILE plan).

Comment: Yes, it is after repeated runs. The PROFILE plan can be found [here](https://imgur.com/a/vRrtC3E). The "CACHE H/M" column is "0/0" for all stages. Is that normal?